# How to specify a ReadConcern to use with Spring's MongoTemplate?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

With the vanilla java [MongoClient](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.6/javadoc/com/mongodb/MongoClient.html) you can specify a read concern for a particular query for example like this:

```
var result = mongoClient.getDatabase("somedb")
                        .getCollection("collection")
                        .withReadConcern(ReadConcern.MAJORITY)
                        .find(..)
```

But I cannot seem to find a way to set the `ReadConcern` using Spring's [MongoTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/MongoTemplate.html). Preferably I'd like to set it for a specific query, but if this is not possible I'm fine with configuring something equivalent to a [WriteConcernResolver](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/WriteConcernResolver.html) (but for read concerns).

Is this possible, and if so how?

I'm using spring-data-mongodb version 3.2.6.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you maybe able to set this on the `TransactionOptions` and `MongoTransactionManager`:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/MongoTransactionManager.html

Example:

```
TransactionOptions transactionOptions = TransactionOptions.builder().readConcern(ReadConcern.LOCAL).writeConcern(WriteConcern.W1).build();
return new MongoTransactionManager(dbFactory.getMongoDatabaseFactory(), transactionOptions);
```

=== Edited ===

How about we take it the MongoClient route, since you stated it works on it?  We could create a MongoTemplate from a given MongoClient instance:

Example:

```
import com.mongodb.ConnectionString;
import com.mongodb.MongoClientSettings;
import com.mongodb.ReadConcern;
import com.mongodb.ReadPreference;
import com.mongodb.WriteConcern;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClients;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.config.AbstractMongoClientConfiguration;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate;

@Configuration
public class DemoApplication extends AbstractMongoClientConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate() {
        return new MongoTemplate(mongoClient(), "someDbName");
    }

    @Override
    public MongoClient mongoClient() {
        final ConnectionString connectionString = new ConnectionString("mongodb://localhost:27017/someDbName");

        MongoClientSettings mongoClientSettings = MongoClientSettings.builder()
                .applyConnectionString(connectionString)
                .readConcern(ReadConcern.DEFAULT)
                .writeConcern(WriteConcern.MAJORITY)
                .readPreference(ReadPreference.primary()).build();

        return MongoClients.create(mongoClientSettings);
    }

    @Override
    protected String getDatabaseName() {
        return "someDbName";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want to have a specific read concern for a particular query and another one for other queries. These queries may not be a part of a transaction.

Comment: @Johan I edited it the answer, but please take it with a grain of salt. I just wrote it, it compiles but not tested during runtime.

Comment: @SMA How to verify is read concern is working properly? Like I used secondary preferred. how do i verify that it is reading from secondary nodes?

Comment: @TarunjeetSinghSalh According to the docs `secondaryPreferred
In most situations, operations read from secondary members but if no secondary members are available, operations read from the primary on sharded clusters.` Therefore I would assume the simplest way is to modify data on the secondary node to be different than the first, and do a READ a few times and see if you get data from the second node or not.  However, If you have a replication mechanism in place, your manual data changes might be overwritten as well.  Not quite sure how you would verify it..